# Potential energy in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, potential-energy, coordinate-systems

I am having trouble deriving the elastic potential energy in cylindrical coordinates for this problem:

[image]

We have $|AP| = 2R\cos(\phi/2)$ (elongation) and $\theta = \phi/2$. The projection axes (defined by unit vectors $ê_{\rho}, ê_{\phi}, ê_{z}$) are attached to point P. The length of the spring at rest is 0 and its spring constant is $k$.

[image: projection axes]

The answer is supposedly $2kR^2\cos^2(\phi/2)$ but I do not understand how I can get there.

I understand that I have to find the path integral so I have computed the projection of the restoring force along $ê_{\phi}$ : $-kR\sin(\phi)dr$, but upon integration this does not yield the correct result.

Can someone please offer a quick walkthrough of the computation (how to correctly use the scalar product etc)?

Comment: What method did you use to get $F_\phi$ ?

Comment: @catalogue_number the angle APO equals \theta and F = -k|AP|

Comment: Did this question come out of a textbook?

Comment: Not sure. Its an exam question though.

Comment: Based on your earlier question it appears that you have no or insufficient background in calculus. If that is correct, you should work on that.

Comment: Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6093/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in determining the force contribution along $\hat{\phi}$. Your only mistake is in the integration. You need to integrate the force *starting* at $\phi = \pi$ to $\phi = \phi$. Since we can say that $dr = Rd\phi$,

$$\int_\pi^\phi F dr = \int_\pi^\phi-kRsin(\phi)*Rd\phi$$

Which, on integration, gives a slightly disguised form of the required result.

There's a useful identity:

$$2\cos^2(\theta/2) \equiv \cos(\theta) + 1$$
 Proof:

$2\cos^2(\theta/2) - 1 $

$=\cos^2(\theta/2) - \sin^2(\theta/2)$

$= \cos(2(\theta/2)) = \cos(\theta)$

Comment: Please do not give full solutions to homework problems.

Comment: The expected result is already stated in the OP's question. How could one structure an answer to give only the required hints?

Comment: Oh, basically these questions are considered off topic. It's better just to not even answer them.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

$$
\mathbf{F}=-k\cdot2R\sin\left(\frac{\omega}{2}\right)\biggl[\sin\left(\frac{\omega}{2}\right),\cos\left(\frac{\omega}{2}\right)\biggr]=-k\,R\left(1-\cos\omega,\sin\omega\right)
\tag{01}
$$

$$
\mathbf{r}=R\left(-\cos\omega,\sin\omega\right) \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}=R\left(\sin\omega,\cos\omega\right)\mathrm{d}\omega 
\tag{02}
$$

$$
\mathbf{F}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}=-k\,R^{2}\sin\omega\mathrm{d}\omega 
\tag{03}
$$

\begin{align}
\mathrm{PE}=\int\limits_{\omega=0}^{\omega=\pi-\phi}\mathbf{F}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r} & =-k\,R^{2}\int\limits_{\omega=0}^{\omega=\pi-\phi}\sin\omega\mathrm{d}\omega =-k\,R^{2}\Bigl[-\cos\omega\Bigr]_{\omega=0}^{\omega=\pi-\phi}\\
&=k\,R^{2}\left(1+\cos\phi\right)= 2\,k\,R^{2}\cos^{2}\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)
\tag{04}
\end{align}

Comment: Please do not give full solutions to homework problems